# How to let android ui thread execute to the end when testing?

Tags: android, junit, tdd

I have a app which will download a file from web. The download action is triggered by clicking a button and then it will start a new thread to download this file.

What I want to do now is to test if the download is succesfull or not. 
So I wrote the following test code :

```
private void testGenerateFile() throws Exception {
    try {
        runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ((EditText)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.edit_server)).setText("http://192.168.120.248/phonebook.xml");
                click(R.id.ok);
            }
        });
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
}
```

But after executing it, the file hasn't been downloaded. But if I add `Thread.sleep(2000)` at the end, the file is generated. But I think this is not a proper solution. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the location where the file is downloaded to, and the size of the file, you could periodically check (till a predefined duration) for the file being created and downloaded. You could assume that the file is successfully downloaded if the file size meets the original size.

Comment: It's a really a good idea. What you mean is that i should continue check whether this file was generator for a while. If after a long time this file wasn't generated, then the download must failed.

Comment: That is correct, unless the app handles the download failure in some other way (like deleting the file altogether). Depends on the app being tested.

Comment: Or maybe the demand to test downloading file isn't very property. I shouldn't testing something about remote resources.

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not understand what you meant by that comment. Your test cases should tell you what is it that you have to test. A good app should handle all error cases gracefully.